# Receiving an SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED only on one page

Tags: python, html, python-requests

this error is really confusing me. I am trying to retrieve some information from a website but haven't really come far.
Even when only trying to do a simple get Request like so:

```
import requests
url = 'https://www.solaxcloud.com/'
s = requests.Session()
s.get(url)
```

It works fine with every other URL except the one I need it for. For this specific URL I receive the following error:

> requests.exceptions.SSLError:
>   HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.solaxcloud.com', port=443): Max retries
>   exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL:
>   CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:852)'),))

I already tried using a header and preparing the request, but I always get the same error. I tried with a lot of other common websites (google, stack overflow, etc.) and they all work. 
I can also put verify=False in the get method, but it doesn't really seem like the right thing to do. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I so I think I found some solutions on my own. If you really don't want to verify you can put the argument verify=False into your requests.

```
s.get(url, verify=False)
```

Definitely not the recommended solution! I didn't know Python doesn't use the computer's certificates, that's why it was only that one site it couldn't verify. You manually have to download the certificate and add it to your certifi package. This link shows an example of how: https://incognitjoe.github.io/adding-certs-to-requests.html

If it is a private certificate you can also put it as a direct path as in verify='pathtocertificate'